# Does BusinessHours diff() method work with standard CreatedDate field in Before Update Trigger?

Tags: apex, businesshours

I will start off with a code snippet:

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert, before update)
{

       BusinessHours defaultHours = [select Id from BusinessHours where IsDefault=true];

        if (Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore)
        {
            for (Case updatedCase : Trigger.new)
            {
                System.debug('CreatedDate: ' + updatedCase.CreatedDate);
                System.debug('System.now: ' + System.now());
                System.debug('Case CreatedDate BusinessHours.diff: ' + BusinessHours.diff(defaultHours.Id, updatedCase.CreatedDate, System.now()));
                System.debug('Control BusinessHours.diff: ' + BusinessHours.diff(defaultHours.Id, Datetime.now().addDays(-1), System.now()));

                // ... other logic
            }
        }
}
```

And the Logs:

> 14:02:43:077 USER_DEBUG [70]|DEBUG|CreatedDate: 2018-08-09 08:27:42
>   14:02:43:077 USER_DEBUG [71]|DEBUG|System.now: 2018-08-09 11:02:43
>   14:02:43:077 USER_DEBUG [72]|DEBUG|Case CreatedDate BusinessHours.diff: 0
>   14:02:43:078 USER_DEBUG [73]|DEBUG|Control BusinessHours.diff:
>   36000000

### Question:

Why `BusinessHours.diff(defaultHours.Id, updatedCase.CreatedDate, System.now())` returns `0`? I suspect the `updatedCase.CreatedDate` causes such a behavior, but I couldn't find any logical explanation for it.

### Update 1:

Using Trigger.Old (I used Trigger.oldMap) didn't work:

```
System.debug('Case CreatedDate BusinessHours.diff: ' + BusinessHours.diff(defaultHours.Id, Trigger.oldMap.get(updatedCase.Id).CreatedDate, System.now()));
```

Debug log:

> 14:52:38:071 USER_DEBUG [72]|DEBUG|Case CreatedDate
>   BusinessHours.diff: 0

### Update 2:

As a workaround (suggested in the comments) it's possible to use a custom formula field that simply references the record's CreatedDate.

**Created_Date_Custom_Formula__c**

```
CreatedDate
```

Trigger:

```
System.debug('Case Created Date Formula BusinessHours.diff: ' + BusinessHours.diff(defaultHours.Id, updatedCase.Created_Date_Custom_Formula__c, System.now()));
```

Debug log:

> 15:11:18:055 USER_DEBUG [75]|DEBUG|Case Created Date Formula
>   BusinessHours.diff: 276690

### Update 3:

One key part that was missing in the initial question was the Business Hours table:

[image]

Note: Timezone for Business Hours is (GMT-05:00) Central Daylight Time (America/Chicago), whereas my timezone is (GMT+02:00)

Comment: What if you take older case? CreatedDate is your timezone, and System.now -- GMT, issue may be in that

Comment: Can you store createdDate in custom datetime field and check the difference with System.now()

Comment: @kurunve, all calculations with dates happen in GMT. Internally CreatedDate is stored in GTM. The timezone comes into play when user sees the record in UI, for example.

Comment: @SantanuBoral, seems that's a workaround for now. But it's so inconvenient and I have to add some code overhead to make sure this field is always populated. I "love" apex.

Comment: Turned out that I can even use a custom formula field to reference the CreatedDate standard field. It's much nicer than a simple custom field. @SantanuBoral, thanks for the original idea.

Comment: I have post that approach as an answer so that others may find this useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a trivial thing - I tested the diff() between two dates when the Business Day for (GMT-05:00) Central Daylight Time (America/Chicago) timezone had not started. My timezone is (GMT+03:00) Kiev.

I created a case record at 11:27 AM in my timezone which in turn was 3:27 AM in GMT-05:00. Obviously when I tried `System.debug('Case CreatedDate BusinessHours.diff: ' + BusinessHours.diff(defaultHours.Id, updatedCase.CreatedDate, System.now()));`, it gave me 0 because both `CreatedDate` and `System.now()` were in the same date but before 7:00 AM (GMT-05:00) which is the start of the business hours. The diff() method just didn't count it and it was correct.

On the contrary `System.debug('Control BusinessHours.diff: ' + BusinessHours.diff(defaultHours.Id, Datetime.now().addDays(-1), System.now()));` showed 10 hours (36000000 miliseconds) because it counted from  3:27 AM (GMT-05:00) **of the previous day** which spanned the business hours of that day.

Answer (score 1):

*Putting comments to the answer, since this approach has solved your purpose.*

You can store the `createdDate` value in the custom field or use formula field to get `CreatedDate` value (*@Eduard's comments*) and use that field in the calculation.

Comment: Have to unmark your answer as accepted because the root case was in the Business Hours start time.

Comment: no issues, ideally when you test business hour related issues always make user's timezone and Business Hour's timezone as same for testing. Otherwise you make get confused with the results